# Ubuntu 16.04 Hyper-v and eth1

Tags: hyper-v

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS under Hyper-V. When adding a second NIC (eth1), upon bootup the host takes eth1's gateway as default instead of eth0's gateway.

Is this normal? How can I get eth0's gw to be default upon boot? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please expand on your question?  Perhaps providing a little more information would be useful, such as logs and screenshots. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your addresses change as well? Use `ip addr` in terminal and observe changes.

If that's the case then try setting the connections manually.

- Choose edit Connections and head to ipv4
- Use subnet as `255.255.255.0`
- Select an Ip address that's different from the router's (host NIC) e.g if the host ip address is `192.168.25.1` you can select any value other than 1 but below 255 (for the last digit) e.g `192.168.25.9`
- the default gateway and(or) DNS is that router's address (`192.168.25.1` in this case)

Sometimes the problem with DHCP enabled network is that when lease expires and it gets a new IP address instead of renewing the old lease.